# How to add Background Image to BottomTabNavigator in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

Is there a way to add a Background Image to the bottom navigation bar

I tried using tab bar component but it did not help.

The code that I am using is

````
//Navigation Options 
<Tab.Navigator
      tabBarOptions={{
        showLabel: false,
        activeTintColor: '#656565',
        inactiveTintColor: '#353B48',
        style: {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        },
      }
    }>

</Tab.Navigator>

 }```
````

Answer (score 0):

I think only option is building your own custom tabBar + icons etc:
And use `ImageBackground` instead of `View` for your image.

```
tabBar={(f) => (
  <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', height: 100 }}>
    {console.log(f.state.routeNames)}
  </View>
)}
```